# App not showing up in "Open with" menu in Drive UI

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I'am writing an app using Google App Engine and I want to integrate it with google drive api. Specifically I want to implement the functionality that when you right click on a txt file in the drive UI, it lets me open the file using my app as described [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/integrate-open#open_files_using_the_open_with_contextual_menu).

I have gone through the oauth2 using decorators in python on the server side and I am able to e.g. read information from drive files from my app.

My app is also listed in Drive under *settings* > *Managing Apps*
But it still does not show up under the *Open With* menu.

I have also enabled the Drive Api in the [developer console](https://console.cloud.google.com), and set a *Open URL* to a URL under my domain and *Default file extension* to *txt*

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I had not enabled the correct scopes in my server-side OAuth2 authorization.

Previously I had only the scope:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
```

However, when I enabled the following scopes

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.install
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
profile
```

It worked